# How can I represent the values of particular row in form of bar chart in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, bar-chart

```
Names mens womens girlkid boykid
Home.  5.   3.      4.    2.
```

How can I put this data on a bar chart?

I've tried the following code

```
Df.set_index("names").plot(kind=bar)
```

But what if too many rows are there how can I choose a particular row for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use x as Names and y as Home.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = df.plot.bar(x='Names', y='Home.', rot=0)
```

for stacked bar chart refer this guide.

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html